# Setting up git with Unity3d project, objects removed when Library is excluded

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, gitignore

I'm currently working on a Unity3d project where I switch a lot between my PC at home and my Mac at work. I've read a bunch of threads on how to type the gitignore-file for using github, and it all works fine. But the ignore-files I've seen so far are all ignoring the Library folder, but doing so will result in the scene getting all broken. All the GameObjects are removed and all I see in my scenes are just a Main Camera Object. I assume there is a reason for not including the Library folder in the git repository, so how would I solve this without adding it?

my gitignore:

```
/[Ll]ibrary/
/[Tt]emp/
/[Oo]bj/
/[Bb]uild/
/[Bb]uilds/
/Assets/AssetStoreTools*

# Autogenerated VS/MD solution and project files
ExportedObj/
*.csproj
*.unityproj
*.sln
*.suo
*.tmp
*.user
*.userprefs
*.pidb
*.booproj
*.svd


# Unity3D generated meta files
*.pidb.meta

# Unity3D Generated File On Crash Reports
sysinfo.txt

# Builds
*.apk
*.unitypackage
```

Answer (score 0):

Try going to Edit -> Project Settings -> Editor and selecting "visible meta files" -- this should cause your meta files to be located outside of the Library folder and help with this issue.

Comment: Tried this as well, but the scene is still not correct when I download the repo  to my PC. I also tried force text.